# If $X \subset R^n$ is contractible, then $X$ is convex.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Prove or refute that a subspace $X \subset R^n$ contractible to a point $x_0 \in X$ is convex, I thik that this is false, but I can't find a counterexample.

Comment: Nearly anything you can draw that is “solid” would be a counterexample as long as it wasn’t convex.

Comment: A very general class of contractible subspaces that aren't usually convex are the *star-shaped* sets: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_domain

Answer (score 2):

Take $X$ to be two lines which meet in one point.

Comment: And the map F will bedefine to F((x,y),t)=(tx,ty) really?

Answer (score 1):

$S^1\backslash\{1\}\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ is homeomorphic to $(0, 2\pi)$, so contractible, but not convex.